# Problem uploading program to Atmega 328 microcontroller

Tags: uploading

I recently bought a Atmel Atmega 328 P-PU microcontroller.I tried uploading a program to it by using the circuitry given in the link.I am using a RS 232 breakout board.Here is the link http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Standalone .I am not able to upload programs to it.It says problem uploading to board or avrdude attempt 1 out of 10 failed.What can I do about it?

Comment: the uploader is a usb to uart bridge

Comment: Did you install the bootloader first?

Comment: Additionally, if you wired ATmega pins directly to RS232 levels without level translation, your chip may be damaged.   You can buy a replacement with a bootloader preinstalled at a small premium, or use another Arduino or a programmer or even some other development board to load the bootloader into a good chip.

Comment: It is a pre bootloaded chip

Comment: You never described the problem.

Comment: Which RS232 breakout board are you using and how have your connected it between your PC and the Atmega chip?

Comment: The problem has been solved by pressing the reset button at the right time.I must have added a 100nf capacitor there.(between DTR and reset)